# I received a 'no space left on device' error during the untarring process, even though I have enough space and sufficient inodes

Tags: linux, filesystems, tar, ext4

1. I'm going to save a lot of small files on disk, so I formatted it with this command:

> sudo mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -T small -i 8192 /dev/sdb

2. I checked the disk as follows:

> sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb

```
fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
e2fsck 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sdb: 11/65536000 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 8680071/524288000 blocks
```

3. Then I mounted it:

> sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/disk

4. I started to untar an archive with ~17 million files:

> tar -xvf archive.tar -C /mnt/disk

```
train_m/233557/10.jpg
tar: train_m/233557: Cannot mkdir: No space left on device
tar: train_m/233557/10.jpg: Cannot open: No such file or directory
train_m/233557/5.jpg
tar: train_m/233557: Cannot mkdir: No space left on device
tar: train_m/233557/5.jpg: Cannot open: No such file or directory
train_m/233557/0.jpg
tar: train_m/233557: Cannot mkdir: No space left on device
tar: train_m/233557/0.jpg: Cannot open: No such file or directory
train_m/492576/
train_m/492576/1.jpg
train_m/492576/2.jpg
train_m/492576/3.jpg
train_m/492576/0.jpg
```

As I understand it, this means that some directories couldn't be extracted while others could.

5. When the archive had been extracted, I received the following message:

> tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Apparently, a few thousand directories (out of ~600k directories) weren't extracted. **How could this have happened?**

After extraction, I checked the space:

> df -i

```
Filesystem              Inodes   IUsed    IFree IUse%
/dev/sdb              65536000 8276432 57259568   13%
```

> df -h

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use%
/dev/sdb               492G   97G  396G  20%
```

P.S. If I format the disk with the default parameters, the archive extracts successfully, but due to the large number of files, I reach the inode limit and cannot add any more data to the disk.

Comment: If your log is correct, one directory failed to mkdir, and then the next succeeded.  Is this right?  Also, I hope you haven't tried to put 600k subdirectories in one directory, as this tends to degrade performance.

Comment: Yes, some directories fail to be created during the unpacking process and, as a result, lose all their contents. These are random directories each time. I've tried formatting the disk and unpacking again, and each time the lost directories are different.

P.S.: On a neighboring machine, I have more than 2 million subdirectories and I haven't noticed any degradation in performance.

Comment: I think ext4 may reduce the degradation.  One suggestion: Try pre-creating all the directories before extracting the tar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding the large_dir option during formatting:

> mkfs.ext4 -O large_dir -m 0 -T small -i 8192 /dev/sdb

Answer (score 0):

The  `-T small` option sets three options:

```
blocksize = 1024
inode_size = 128
inode_ratio = 4096
```

The third gives you more inodes.  The first two limit the size of files.
You only want the third.  Try `-T news` instead - it just does the inode_ratio.